# Facebook link evaluation

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

I believe Facebook has a developer tool that "looks" at your webpage and tells you what the OG tools see, and what they'll pull when a page is shared in someone's timeline (which image, which description and title, etc.). It's really nifty for evaluating the sharing experience for a page.

Does anyone know what this tool is? I used it a few months ago but I can't seem to find it now, curious if it still exists or Facebook scrapped it.

Thanks!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: I found it! Facebook Linter or Debugger, here's the link if this helps anyone else: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Open Graph debugger is at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug